# App Crashes when requesting Location in iOs 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, xcode8

In my application I use to get the location data and send it back to the server. the app worked pretty good in previous versions and it crashes in iOs 10. i'm using Xcode 8. the following message shows in the log.

```
Couldn't find the "com.apple.private.externalaccessory.showallaccessories" entitlement
[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/delta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EE3BD084-BA73-44F6-AD95-BE49BBE838AC/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
[MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

so How can I fix this.

Comment: did you add **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** and **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** Keys in .plist file ?

Comment: Have you added NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your plist ?

Comment: @Rajat +1 for same thought

Comment: @Wolverine yeah that is the most common reason for crash in iOS10

Comment: see this http://forums.structure.io/t/crash-witch-xcode-8-0-and-ios-10-due-to-entitlement-missing/6753/2

Comment: do U mean "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description" & "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" in the plist or some thing else ??? @Rajat & Wolverine

Comment: Yes those two keys, have you added these in your plist ?

Comment: yes... I've added those

Comment: it might be helps you http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/

Comment: I went through this before I get here :) @himanth

Comment: @SamanthaWithanage are you using any external accessories ?

Comment: @ Wolverine, no i'm not using.... should I do this for every thing, I mean If I'm using camera, Should I define it on plist

Comment: thats it. I'm Using camera too. thanks Guys.

Comment: Yes. Please refer my answer. It contains all details of usage description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 10, If you want to access to private data, a significant change  is that you must declare ahead of time or your App will crash.

If you are using any of the framework listed below

> Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, Photos, Bluetooth Sharing, Microphone,
>   Camera, Location, Health, HomeKit, Media Library, Motion, CallKit,
>   Speech Recognition, SiriKit

You have to declare the description in **Info.plist**

Here is the full list of Info.plist keys which you have to declare for iOS10.

```
    <!-- Photo Library -->
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use</string>

    <!-- Camera -->
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use</string>

    <!-- Microphone -->
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) microphone use</string>

    <!-- Location -->
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) location use</string>

    <!-- Location When In Use -->
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) location use</string>

    <!-- Location Always -->
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) always uses location </string>

    <!-- Calendars -->
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) calendar events</string>

    <!-- Reminders -->
    <key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) reminder use</string>

    <!-- Contacts -->
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) contact use</string>

    <!-- Motion -->
    <key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) motion use</string>

    <!-- Health Update -->
    <key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) heath update use</string>

    <!-- Health Share -->
    <key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) heath share use</string>

    <!-- Bluetooth Peripheral -->
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) Bluetooth Peripheral use</string>

    <!-- Media Library -->
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) media library use</string>

    <!-- Siri -->
    <key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) siri use</string>

    <!-- HomeKit -->
    <key>NSHomeKitUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) home kit use</string>

    <!-- SpeechRecognition -->
    <key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) speech use</string>

    <!-- VideoSubscriber -->
    <key>NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) tvProvider use</string>
```

Also

Apps that are able to communicate with an external accessory must declare the protocols they support in their **Info.plist** file.

> To declare the protocols your app supports, you must include the
>   **UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols** key in your app’s Info.plist
>   file. This key contains an array of strings that identify the
>   communications protocols that your app supports.

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 1):

Goto app **Info.Plist** file and added the privacy key according to your requirement.

**Location :**
Key    :  Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) location use

Key    :  Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
Value  :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) location use

If you added the above privacy keys and still crashing the app. Then enable the appropriate "**Capabilities**"

**Example**: If you are using "**Uses Bluettoth LE accessories**"

**Project -> Capabilities -> Background Modes -> Uses Bluetooth LE accessories.**